# How to convert a Pandas DataFrame into a valid MLserver Predict V2-encoded payload?

Tags: python, pandas, seldon

I recently found the KServe and MLserver projects which are open source tools for serving ML models. These are great. What's not so great is that these both use a (new to me) and novel formatting for inference inputs, documented here: https://kserve.github.io/website/modelserving/inference_api/

An input looks like

```
{
  "id" : "42",
  "inputs" : [
    {
      "name" : "input0",
      "shape" : [ 2, 2 ],
      "datatype" : "UINT32",
      "data" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "input1",
      "shape" : [ 3 ],
      "datatype" : "BOOL",
      "data" : [ true ]
    }
  ]
}
```

While I understand this format from the docs, I don't understand how I'm supposed to easily convert a Pandas DataFrame into this format. I've looked online for "Dataframe to MLserve V2 format converter" but I can't find anything.

Does anyone know how I would go about making this conversion? Surely I wouldn't have to write my own.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V2 Inference Protocol can be thought of as a lower-level spec. It doesn't try to define how to encode higher-level data types (e.g. a Pandas Dataframe) and leaves this to the inference servers themselves.

Based on this, MLServer introduces its own conventions which, if followed, ensure that the payload gets converted into a higher-level Python data type. These are covered in the [Content Types](https://mlserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/content-type.html) section of the docs.

In particular, for Pandas Dataframes, the simplest way would be to use the *"codecs"* which were introduced in MLServer 1.1.0. These include a set of helpers which let you do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

from mlserver.codecs import PandasCodec

foo = pd.DataFrame({
  "A": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
  "B": ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"],
  "C": ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
})

v2_request = PandasCodec.encode_request(foo)
```

Alternatively, you can also craft your own payload following the [rules](https://mlserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/content-type.html#pandas-dataframe) outlined in the docs (i.e. each column goes into a separate input, etc.).